# Calculate quantity using an unrelated field in dax

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

[image]

```
ID 
001 
002

REQ
ID   ITEM  QUANT
001  chips 20
002  chips 100

SCHEDULE
1 001 cleaning 
1 002 normal
2 001 normal
2 002 remodel
3 001 normal
3 002 remodel
4 001 remodel
4 002 cleaning
```

item = corn chips

| id_store |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | phase | cleaning | normal | normal | remodel |
|  | quant | 0 | 20 | 20 | 5 |
| 002 | phase | normal | remodel | remodel | cleaning |
|  | quant | 100 | 5 | 5 | 0 |

I want to calculate a quant given a store phase. if the store is cleaning then its 0 quant, if remodeling then 5 quant else its the quant from requirements.

normally I would do this with a switch statement in dax but the phase data is not in my table. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out a simple switch statement looking at different tables works just fine.

```
Num Items := 
VAR T = sum(REQ[Quant])
RETURN
SWITCH(
  TRUE(),
  VALUES(SCHEDULE[PHASE]) = "cleaning", 0,
  VALUES(SCHEDULE[PHASE]) = "remodeling", 5,
  T
)
```